# Why is Spring Security 6 not hitting the validate method of my OAuth2TokenValidator?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-resource-server

I have the following code...

```java
public class AudienceValidator implements OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> {

    private final String audience;

    public AudienceValidator(String audience) {
        this.audience = audience;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt jwt) {
        if (jwt.getAudience().contains(audience)) {
            return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
        } else {
            return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(error);
        }
    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I have confirmed it stops inside the `jwtDecode` method using the debugger but when I send a message with an Access Token, I don't see it hitting the validation function and it doesn't seem to confirm that the audience is correct. Am I missing something? Why is the validate function not getting called as expected?

I also tried to manually add the JWTDecoder...

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                                .decoder(jwtDecoder())
                        )
                );
        return http.build();
    }
```

And I still don't hit the debug breakpoint at

`if (jwt.getAudience().contains(audience)) {`

I also tried using the Reactive Decoder like...

```
    @Bean
    ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder)
                ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
```

This still didn't hit the debugger.